# Looking for an advice. Mistake somewhere. HTML and JS

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote a script which counts some time and then shows an image.

I added a button to give the option to stop counting whenever I want. I tried to make a function which is going to make the variable `seconds` equal to 0, which in this case should start the "else" loop in the `timer()` function, which is where it should end counting.

Instead of attribute a button to make a `surrender()` function, can I do it with a background (Line 7).

How should I loop whole operation after a few seconds of waiting (Line 30)?

I'm new to programming, so I would ask for possibly easiest to understand code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body id="bckgrd" bgcolor="white"; onload="timer();">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var clock;

        // ?? document.getElementById("tlo").onclick=  surrender(); ??

        function timer () {
            clearInterval(clock);
            var start = new Date().getTime();
            clock = setInterval(function() {
                var seconds = Math.round(15 - (new Date().getTime() - start) / 1000);
                if (seconds >= 0)
                    document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = seconds;
                else 
                    clearInterval(clock);

                    if (seconds==0) document.getElementById("photo").innerHTML='<img src="sweetpug.jpg"/>';

                    // ?? setTimeout(timer(), 2000) ??

            }, 1000);
        }

        function surrender(){
        seconds==0
        }

    </script>
    <button id= "button" onclick="surrender();">give up</button>
    <p id="seconds">15</p>
    <div id="photo">

    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were several things wrong with your code (see comments in the snippet below), but the biggest obstacle to your surrender function is that even though you set `seconds` to zero, when the timing function runs again, that value is wiped out when `seconds` is reset back to your date minus your start.  Instead of worrying about seconds, just make surrender do what it needs to: stop the clock, show the image and set the counter to zero:

```js
// Get DOM element references and store them in variables instead
// of scanning for them in your code later.
var btn = document.getElementById("btnSurrender");
var pic = document.getElementById("photo");
var secondsP = document.getElementById('seconds');

// If you don't know what the value of a variable is going to be
// it's best to initialize it to null as a starting value so that
// you can understand what is happening during debugging.

// Variable to store reference to running timer
var clock = null;

// Wire button up to click event handler. Do this using the 
// W3C DOM Event Model standard technique and not as an inline
// HTML event handling attribute.
btn.addEventListener("click", surrender);

function timer () {
  // Stop any previously running timers
  clearInterval(clock);
  
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  
  clock = setInterval(function() {
             // Variable to store the seconds that tick away
             // Because this is declared within the timing function
             // you can't access it from surrender, which is what you 
             // were originally trying to do. If that were the case, you should
             // have declared it outside of both functions so that either could
             // get to it. But, since my answer isn't going to need secons anywhere
             // else but here, we'll leave it here.
             var seconds = Math.round(15 - (new Date().getTime() - start) / 1000);
    
             // Always include the curly braces around your if statement's branches
             // This avoids bugs later on
             if (seconds >= 0) {
               secondsP.textContent = seconds;
             } else {
               clearInterval(clock);
             }

             if (seconds === 0) {
               pic.innerHTML='<img src="sweetpug.jpg" alt="sweetpug.jpg">';
             }
  }, 1000);
}

function surrender(){
 //seconds = 0; // You had seconds == 0, == is for comparison, not assignment
  
 // Stop any previously running timers
 clearInterval(clock);
 pic.innerHTML='<img src="sweetpug.jpg" alt="sweetpug.jpg">';
 secondsP.textContent = 0;
}

timer();
```

```html
<button id= "btnSurrender">give up</button>
    <p id="seconds">15</p>
    <div id="photo"></div>
```